# SignalR Windows Service Won't Connect To Hub

Tags: c#, windows-services, signalr

I am using SignalR in my web project. I first created the hub as a console application, to allow for easier debugging, it worked flawlessly. I recently tried to switch SignalR over to a windows service and I keep getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined` when trying to reference `client` on any function

```
$.connection.hub.url = "https://localhost:8080/signalr";
var dc = $.connection.deviceController
dc.client.anything = ...
```

This is odd, because I can navigate to `https://localhost:8080/signalr/hubs` manually without issue. My service app is almost an exact replica of the console app, simply just starting the hubs in the `OnStart()` method.

StartUp.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

OnStart in service

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Status("Service starting...");
    const string url = "https://*:8080";

    try
    {
        WebApp.Start<Startup>(url); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Status(e.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

Any insight here?

**EDIT:** I may also point out that `deviceController` hub is in a referenced class library, but I didn't think that would be an issue since it is referenced properly.

Comment: Can you check for any other JavaScript error occurring before the one you reported? Also, if you use something like the Network panel from Chrome's Dev Tools, can you see if anything goes wrong there?

Comment: @Wasp Nothing going wrong there. I added `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(typeof(DeviceController).Assembly.FullName);`, which seemed to fix the original issue, but now I seem to be having trouble with files that `DeviceController` references...